# Animation restarts repeatedly when mouse touches the boundaries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I have a problem with animation on an image Mouse Over Event trigger in WPF. When the mouse touches the boundaries of the Image and stands still, the animation restarts repeatedly forever until moving mouse. What should I do in this case to stop it and the trigger fires just one time?

My code is:

```
<Image Source="/Project_12;component/Images/cancel-64.png" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" Stretch="Uniform">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotatex" Angle="0" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="sb">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                     By="0"        
                     To="90" 
                     Duration="0:0:.5" 
                     FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sb" />
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: The animation moves the image out from under the mouse. One way to fix this would be to define a static, transparent area over the animated element and define your triggers there.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Would you please explain more what should I do now and what would be the code?

Comment: Working on an example, should be done in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem of your animation is, that you use the `IsMouseOver` property of the animated object. As soon as the image gets rotated, you move the HitTestArea of the image "out of the way" which causes the `IsMouseOver` property to become false, ending the animation and therefore causing an infinite loop. I added a blue border to show the HitTestArea of the image to highlight the problem.

[image]

What you need to do, is create another, static area (with a transparent Background to make sure it has a HitTestArea) and use the `IsMouseOver` property of that are instead (red border).

[image]

That way, even if the image "moves away" from the mouse cursor, the `IsMouseOver` property of the other element will be unaffected by the moving image.

An alternative approach would be to use a circle as the HitTestArea since it won't be affected by rotation.

Source Code of above example:

```
<Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" Width="40" Height="40">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Blue" Width="36" Height="36" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotatex" Angle="0" />
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                     By="0"        
                                     To="90" 
                                     Duration="0:0:.2" 
                                     FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                     By="90"        
                                     To="0" 
                                     Duration="0:0:.2" 
                                     FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="32" Height="32" Stretch="Uniform" Source="cancel.png"/>
    </Border>
</Border>
```